# How to modify strings in a pandas dataframe (regex?)

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

Suppose I have the following rows in a Pandas DataFrame:

```
970 P-A1-1019-03-C15,15 23987896    1   8
971 P-A1-1019-06-B15,15 23251711    4   8
972 P-A1-1019-08-C15,15 12160034    2   8
973 P-A1-1020-01-D15,15 8760012     1   8
```

I'd like to alter the second column to remove the ",15" from the string.  Desired end state would be like this:

```
970 P-A1-1019-03-C15    23987896    1   8
971 P-A1-1019-06-B15    23251711    4   8
972 P-A1-1019-08-C15    12160034    2   8
973 P-A1-1020-01-D15    8760012     1   8
```

The thing to remove won't always be ",15", as it could be ",10", ",03", ",4", etc.  Additionally, some rows in the input are differently formatted, and may look like this:

```
4   RR00-0,2020338  24380076    4   12
5   RR00-0,2020738  10562767    2   12
6   ,D              24260808    1   12
7   ,D              23521158    1   12
```

Initially, I'm only interested in the cases where the string DOES fit the form of "P-A1-1019-03-C15", so it would be nice to be able to drop rows which don't match that specific format.

Is there a built in way to do this kind of processing, or will I need to iterate over every row manually?

Comment: Your first thing is easy just do `df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(',15','')` for the second you can filter using a regex expression something like `df[df['col'].str.contains(regex)]`

Comment: will that str.replace(',15','') work for the case where the thing to remove is ',11'?

Comment: No it looks for exact matches, it depends on how varied your data is, you could just say slice the strings: `df['col'] = df['col'].str.[:-3]` which will strip the last 3 characters off (I think, I may be off by one) or do this: `df['col'] = df['col'].str[:15]` if you want the first 16 characters

Comment: Then I could do the filter with `df[df['col'].str.contains(regex)]` first, then, once all the strings are uniformly formatted, strip the last three...

Comment: Something like that but it may be easier still to say `df[df['col'].str.len() >=16]` if all the duff values are less than that length, a regex pattern is better so long as it is precise enough to match the data you expect

Comment: @TraxusIV, did the below solution solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

This should remove all ',15' values:

```
dataframe['string column'] = dataframe['string column'].apply(lambda value:[value].split(',')[0] if [value].split(',')[0] == '15' else value)
```

This should remove all ',15' values if they are in the format you provided:

```
dataframe['string column'] = dataframe['string column'].apply(lambda value:[value].split(',')[0] if ([value].split(',')[0] == '15') & ('P-A1-' in value) else value)
```